# New WAMP 2.4 installation - http_get() undefined

Tags: php, wampserver, pecl

I just installed WAMP 2.4 and tried to do this request. I'm using PHP v5.4.12 and it says PECL has been bundled since PHP v5.3...what am I missing here? I don't see pecl/php_html as options to turn on as extensions.

Comment: PECL itself may be bundled, but you would still need to `pecl install pecl_http` http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php

Comment: Further, you probably need to make sure you are installing PECL http 1.x, not the newer 2.x line, since it is completely changed, and I don't know if `http_get()` still exists in its old form.